# Can React Native apps be tested in a browser?

Tags: testing, reactjs, react-native, simulator

Realizing that React Native apps are designed to be developed / tested using simulators, is it possible to use a web browser to also test an application?

Services such as https://rnplay.org/ exist, however my concern is it's powered by https://appetize.io/ it might be limited by the # of minutes per month.  I'd also like to utilize free / open-source technology to accomplish this, as compared to a paid screen streaming service.

Along these lines, in order to test the app in a browser, would the app be required to use one or more libraries which allow the app to be run in both React Native and also simply React?  I'd like to find an alternative to this particular approach as I'd like to code for React Native specifically.

Comment: limited, but something to play with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-for-web

Comment: thanks @tokland will check it out - I think there will come a day when we can build natively using faster environments than simulators

Comment: So much for naming this a 'write once run anywhere' !

Comment: sandbox might be a good alternative choice https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-wind-ftpq0

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, React Native can be tested only in mobile simulators like IOS and Android

Update:
Facebook has given a beautiful starter pack for React Native.

[Introducing Create React Native App](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app)

Using this, you can run the app in your mobile using expo app(https://expo.io). It syncs using QR code.

Comment: Just a note on some Expo restriction for impoverished developers: Expo's IDE on Windows requires 64-bit. On MacOs the IDE requires you to log in on the internet. So far I have not succeeded in getting Expo to send a build to my USB-connected Android device from the commandline without internet but it may turn out to be possible ...

Comment: Working well for me

Answer (score 26):

Yes! That's very much possible with [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web). Here are a couple of related, useful resources to get started:

- [React Native Web Starter](https://github.com/joefazz/react-native-web-starter)
- [A guide to combine React and ReactNative into one codebase](https://medium.com/@yannickdot/write-once-run-anywhere-with-create-react-native-app-and-react-native-web-ad40db63eed0)

Comment: Interesting.. I guess they expect all the code to be written using native tags.. Need to check if we can actually UI properly with all its quirks in a browser or not..

Comment: excellent, pls note this need to be the top answer as this is an affirmative

Answer (score 17):

You can use Expo Snack  https://snack.expo.io/ to instantly test your code on a device (using QR code ) or in the browser. For more information, you can go thtrough this article. https://blog.expo.io/sketch-a-playground-for-react-native-16b2401f44a2