# How to run react native application web browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native, but I don't know how to run it in a browser, I tried searching in google but I didn't find anything, please give me a suggestion on how to run a react native in a browser

Comment: What do you mean running in a Browser? React Native is for Mobile Development, so you would need something like Android Studio to run a Mobile Emulator. Maybe you want to run *normal* React instead? What is your goal?

Comment: Actually I am interested in this question as well. I have made a react native app myself and I'd like to include it into my portfolio, which is a website.

Maybe the OP has a similar goal.

There's snacks.expo.io but it doesn't work for my app.

OP, why do you want to run it in a browser? If you're just wanting to see how your app appears live, you can simply use expo and show it on a simulated phone, or even on a real phone that runs the expo app. If you want to show it to the world, it's a bit more difficult.You can see if snack.expo.io works for you, but if it doesn't, it'll be tricky

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can React Native apps be tested in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973914/can-react-native-apps-be-tested-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 0):

No, React Native can be tested only in mobile simulators like IOS and Android.

Using Expo you can run the app in your mobile using expo app(https://expo.io). It syncs using QR code.